# Validate Subscription/Methods Origin

Tags: security, meteor, publish-subscribe, ddp

I used the [DDP tool](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-ddp-tools) against [crater.io](http://crater.io) using the command:

`ddp --host crater.io --port 80 subscribe postsList 10`

I'm connect to DDP from my terminal, so it's really to crawl the entire website. I can easily build an API and suck data in real-time. I'm subscribing to `postLists` outside the browser, the place where it's supposed to be subscribed from. If a subscription takes place outside the browser, I want to block it!

If the subscription uses `this.userId` to check for login is ok but a website like [crater.io](http://crater.io) doesn't ask a login to show you the most recent posts, It makes no sense to ask for a login for some subscriptions.

**We're offering competitors free real-time updates of our database.**

This makes crawling a much easier task and you get real-time updates for free.
How can I detect that a subscription/method is not being called from the browser that loaded the entire Meteor application?

Comment: you can't, anything can be faked

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is basically the way Meteor was designed to work.

Besides, anything that's publicly accessible online is also inherently crawlable. So this is a bit like asking how you can publish a page online, but prevent people from downloading its content with `curl`.

Comment: The problem here is not the crawler but the RAM and CPU (Mergebox) because of the real-time updates. An outsider is not going to connect via DDP every X minutes/hours, he's going to listen and get fresh updates. This might not be an issue today but as Meteor popularity grows this will be a common attack vector. I can easily waste your server, there's no DDP connections limit. A "good enough" defence would be to force the attacker to use `phantomjs` (RAM limit) and load the page to get access to the data. I would love see MDG taking cares of this.

Comment: Oh ok, so you're talking more about something like a DoS attack. I'm afraid I don't really know enough about that to provide an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  MySecureMethod : function(){
    if(this.connection.clientAddress !== 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'){
      throw new Meteor.Error('conexão DDP não permitida para esse host');
    }
  }
});
```